# Is it possible to add different language support for voice over in iPhone swift

Tags: ios, iphone, accessibility, voiceover, espeak

I would like to add a different language for voice over service in iPhone. Is it possible to add language besides apple provided language for voice over in iPhone.

Is it possible to add language support by eSpeak library in iOS.

Please help.

Comment: did you find any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're asking for but in settings > general > accessibility > voiceover > speech, there's an "add new language..." section at the bottom.  Once you add a language, then you can go to "rotor languages" and add that language to your rotor so you can manually switch languages if needed.